# Word wrap or finding soft hyphens in SVG <text>

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, c3.js, hyphenation

I have a c3-chart with long labels. Using the multiline-parameter wraps the line at the end of the available space, not at the orthographically correct point. So the town name "Kroppenstedt", which is slightly too long for the line, results in:

```
<tspan>Kroppensted</tspan>
<tspan>t</tspan>
```

Instead of, f.i.:

```
<tspan>Kroppen-</tspan>
<tspan>stedt</tspan>
```

To get correct word wraps I tried using libraries for hyphenisation, such as hypher. It inserts soft hyphens (shy), but these don't work with the SVG text elements created by d3/c3.

I tried finding the last shy-entity (or space) before the end of the available space in order to manually insert a new tspan with all the text following the line break position, but I can't find the indices of the shy-entities.

```
$(element).html(); //returns the string without shy
element.innerHTML; //returns the string without shy; also true for outerHTML, textContent
```

So I can't use indexOf() or replace() as suggested in other questions. I can only see the soft wraps when logging the tspan-element, and as an SVG element it doesn't offer string methods.

SVG foreignObject doesn't seem to be supported in all browsers and last year, about 20% of our website's users still used IE, so that solution would not be ideal.

Am I overlooking a way to obtain correct hyphenisation in SVG elements? Is there another way to find soft wraps?

Here's what I tried so far:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
        $('g.tick text tspan').hyphenate('de');
    });
    
    
d3.selectAll('.c3-axis-x .tick text tspan')
    .each(function(d,i){
        var lineLength = 60;
        var self = d3.select(this);
        console.log(this); //that's the only way I can see the soft wraps

        var esc = $(this).html().replace(/&shy;/g, /\u00AD/); //or any other replacement character
        $(this).html(esc);

        var break_chars = ["&shy;", " "]; //or /\u00AD/
        var wrap_pos = [];

        $(break_chars).each(function() {
            var start = 0;
            while (start !== -1) {
                var pos = text.indexOf(this, start);

                if (pos !== -1) {
                    start = pos+1;
                    wrap_pos.push(pos);
                } else {
                    start = -1
                }
            }
        });

    // find the last break_pos before the end of the line and create 
    // a new tspan with all the text following it
```

Comment: Have you tried [typesettable](https://github.com/palantir/typesettable)? It claims to do hyphenation.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it! Though I don't see any language-specific patterns there, which makes me wonder if it works for languages other than English.